# Advanced autocomplete input

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

Just learning my way around MVC3 and JQuery and I need to do some fairly advanced stuff, but nothing I don't think anyone else has done before.  So if you can point me in the right direction that would be great.

I have a textbox with a list of authors that I have managed to populate with an autocomplete list from the database (Oracle using EF4). Very nice too.  But I need to build on that.

[image]

basically the user needs to:

- select 1 or more authors (autocomplete on)
- the selected authors should be persisted in some way (e.g. a list etc)
- the user need to be able to remove authors that have been added.
- if the user adds an author that isn't in the list this needs to be earmarked in some way as a new user (at least I need to know in code) and this should be inserted in the author table appropriately.
- in the background I need to retain an ID link (from the database) with the authors name so I can update the database properly.  This may form part of an answer to the previuos point, as a NEW author will not have an ID so do an insert statement.

Hopefully that makes some sense and I don't thinks it's crazy complicated, just my lack of knowing where to look and some code hints :)

**UPDATE**

*So after a bit of hunting around - I think I have found a nice plugin that might do the vast majority of what I want - its called tokenInput.  Not sure how to format the JSON just yet, as it needs it in a specific format, and not sure about earmarking new authors either.  But just giving it a shot now....*

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Answer (score 0):

In order to format to Json you could create a new collection of anonymous objects and then serialize it to json, I have done that like this:

```
var anonymousList= from t in db.YourTable 
                                 where ... something ....
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     id=t.id,
                                     name=t.name
                                 };
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serialized = serializer.Serialize(anonymousList);
return View(new ViewModel { Serialized = serialized });
```

Then you should return your json to your view, I usually add a Parameter to my ViewModel. Then you'll need to assign that string to a javascript variable:

```
<script>
    var myVariable = @Html.Raw(Model.Serialized);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I have just got more into the code now, and I have found that you don't need to do any extra work to get the correct format out, or at least it understands the default JSON output from the MVC framework.  But thanks.